# Show some set of linear transformations is an irreducible set

Tags: abstract-algebra, linear-transformations

This is Ex.6.4.15(a) from Herstein's Topics in Algebra, 2Ed.

> Let $F$ be the field of real numbers.
>
> (a) Prove that the set
>   $$\mathscr M=\left\{\begin{pmatrix}
>      0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
>      -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>      0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>      0 & 0 & -1 & 0
>     \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
>      0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
>      0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
>      0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
>      -1 & 0 & 0 & 0
>     \end{pmatrix}\right\}$$
>   is an irreducible set.

Here, $V$ is an $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$; and the nonempty set, $\mathscr M$, of linear transformations in $A(V)$ is called an *irreducible* set if the only subspaces of $V$ invariant under $\mathscr M$ are $(0)$ and $V$. I tried to prove by showing that subspaces of dimension of 1, 2 and 3 are all non-invariant under $\mathscr M$, but failed with dimension 2. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: When is a subspace $W$ called invariant under a mapping $f$? Is it when $f(W) \subseteq W$, or when $f(W) = W$? In the present case, it's immaterial, since both mappings are invertible.

Comment: The subspace $W$ of $V$ is *invariant under* $T\in A(V)$ if $WT\subseteq W$ (or $T(W)\subseteq W$ equivalently).

Answer (score 0):

Identify $V = \mathbb{R}^4$ with $\mathbb{C}^2$ in the obvious way. Then the first mapping takes $(z_1,z_2)$, to $(-iz_1,-iz_2) = -i(z_1,z_2)$. It is easy to see that an $\mathbb{R}$-subspace $W$ of $\mathbb{C}^2$ that is stable under this mapping amounts to the same thing as a $\mathbb{C}$-subspace of $\mathbb{C}^2$. Apart from $\{0\}$ and $V$, this can only be a $\mathbb{C}$-line. Therefore let $W$ be a $\mathbb{C}$-line in $V$.

The second mapping is $(z_1,z_2) \mapsto (i\overline{z_2},-i\overline{z_1})$. If $(z_1,z_2) \in W$, then $(i\overline{z_2},-i\overline{z_1})$, hence $(-\overline{z_2},\overline{z_1})$ must also belong to $W$. It follows that we must have 
$$\begin{vmatrix} z_1 & -\overline{z_2} \\ z_2 & \overline{z_1} \end{vmatrix} = 0,$$
whence $|z_1|^2 + |z_2|^2 = 0$, hence $z_1, z_2 = 0$, contradicting the fact that $W$ is a line.

Hence the family $M$ is irreducible.

Comment: Thanks for your help. But it's not so clear to me how to identify $\mathbb R^4$ with $\mathbb C^2$. Could you give some hint on it?

Comment: $(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)$ corresponds to $(x_1 + ix_2,x_3 + ix_4)$.